# Accessing web application over internet on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, web-deployment, portforwarding

I have deployed a web application on a Windows 7 machine running on tomcat 7. I have given it a static IP disabled firewall, forwarded port for router, however I am still not able to access the application from over the internet. Obviously, I can access it on the same machine using localhost or the machines internal ip address on port 8080.

Additionally the HTTP request returns with response 200 OK however I cant access the web application. When I use the public IP address and try to access the URL, I get special characters in Internet Explorer and Firefox when I look at the browser tools. On Chrome I get a windows download message to download a file.

What am I doing wrong? Can you guys please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work from other machines in the same LAN?

Comment: @ gfelisberto thank you for your reply. Yes, I am able to access it over other computers in LAN. There is no issue. Its externally I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works from other hosts on your LAN and not from the outside it is something in your router/fw and outside the scope of this site.

If you have a router from your ISP it is probably easier to get help from the ISP or some local forum were users of the ISP gather.

Comment: There was a problem with router. Port 8080 was blocked and creating conflict with some other service. I changed the port in server.xml of tomcat and configured router with mapping for the new port. It worked! thanks for your replies guys.

Answer (score 0):

Could be setup of your the software net filter/routher/isp provider.. 
Definitely not a Tomcat 7.x issue.

Router: it can block certain inbound/outbound connections from a range of port, where your Tomcat application server is running. To test, like gfelisberto said: is to access it via the LAN connected device firstly. Secondly in LAN it might work, however router can also block the connections to outer world.

ISP provider: to test the easiest one is to ask directly, are there any rules about your servers as a client.

Windows firewall: Start Menu->Control Panel->Windows Firewall-> Other settings-> To test Inbound/Outbound connection rules, if you have Windows 7(mine is Finnish localized, the translation is close to English one)

Comment: Yes and I am looking for some help please. This cannot be an answer. Perhaps you could have added this post as a comment. Can you tell me what could be the problem with filter/routher/isp provider ?